# Swift Node Tree to complex Json

Tags: json, swift, macos, d3.js

I'm working on a tool written with swift that needs to export a tree to json. I've been following Swift tree approach described [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1053-swift-algorithm-club-swift-tree-data-structure) as a guide.

I create a tree using the following code

```
class Node {
  var value: String
  var children: [Node] = []
  weak var parent: Node?

  init(value: String) {
    self.value = value
  }

  func add(child: Node) {
    children.append(child)
    child.parent = self
  }
}

let beverages = Node(value: "beverages")

let hotBeverages = Node(value: "hot")
let coffee = Node(value: "coffee")

let coldBeverages = Node(value: "cold")
let water = Node(value: "water")
let soda = Node(value: "soda")

beverages.add(child: hotBeverages)
hotBeverages.add(child: coffee)

beverages.add(child: coldBeverages)
coldBeverages.add(child: water)
coldBeverages.add(child: soda)
```

Now I need to export this code to json. I'm passing it into webkit so I can load a [hierarchal tree via D3](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy). This means I need the export it so it matches the following format...

```
[
 {
  "name": "beverages",
  "children": [
    {
     "name": "cold", 
     "children": [
      {"name": "water"}, 
      {"name": "soda"}
    ]},
    {
      "name": "warm", 
      "children": [
        {"name": "coffee"}
      ]
    }]
  }
]
```

I've seen a lot of posts about exporting swift to basic json, but can't quite wrap my head around doing it with a tree like this. Any help would be appreciated!

Note: I don't need pretty printed json. That's just for readability here

Comment: Your JSON-like data are not valid.

Comment: No? It loads fine for me via javascript. Happy to fix it if you want to tell me what you'd like to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to make `Node` conform to `Encodable`. The only tricky step you need to do is to only encode `children` in case it has any elements, otherwise only encode `value`. You also need to declare a `CodingKey` conformant `enum` to tell `Encodable` to encode the `value` property using the JSON key `name` rather than `value`.

```
extension Node: Encodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case value = "name"
        case children
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(value, forKey: .value)
        if !children.isEmpty {
            try container.encode(children,forKey: .children)
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
do {
    let encodedBevarages = try JSONEncoder().encode(beverages)
    print(String(data: encodedBevarages, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Encoding failed")
} catch {
    error
}
```

Output:

> {"name":"beverages","children":[{"name":"hot","children":[{"name":"coffee"}]},{"name":"cold","children":[{"name":"water"},{"name":"soda"}]}]}

Comment: Yeah, much better than my answer.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks so much